# i can't get my json object right

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var ppc = {
    "cpu" : [
        //intel cpu
        {"name" : "Pentium-G4400", "price" : "240", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i3-6100", "price" : "520", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i3-3240", "price" : "614", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1155"},
        {"name" : "i3-6300", "price" : "745", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i5-4460", "price" : "850", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1150"},
        {"name" : "i5-6400", "price" : "850", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i5-4690", "price" : "950", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1150"},
        {"name" : "i5-6600K", "price" : "1100", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i7-4790", "price" : "1300", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1150"},
        {"name" : "i7-6700", "price" : "1500", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "1151"},
        {"name" : "i7-6800K", "price" : "2250", "make" : "intel", "socket" : "2011"},
        //AMD cpu
        {"name" : "A8-7650K", "price" : "495", "make" : "amd", "socket" : "FM2"},
        {"name" : "FX-8350", "price" : "800", "make" : "amd", "socket" : "AM3"},
        {"name" : "FX-8370", "price" : "1010", "make" : "amd", "socket" : "AM3"}

]};
```

hey, im pretty new to javascript and im working on a project, im trying to get this json to work, i cant get it to work, do you see something i dont see in the code?
it has more like "cpu" on the original code, this is the function im trying to create:

```
function getRes() {
    "use strict";
    //use - 1 - gaming | 2 - video edit | 3 - music creator || 4 - photo edit | 5 - developer | 6 - simple
    var cpub, gpub, mbb, ramb, memoryb, ssdb, fcpu, fgpu, fmb, fram, fmem, fssd, bud, cp, use, s, i, pc = JSON.parse(ppc);
    cp = 1000;
    bud = document.getElementById("budget");
    //use = ((document.getElementById("use")||{}).value)||"";
    //use = $("#use option:selected").html();
//    if(use === 3 || use === 5 ||| use === 6)cpu = bud * 50 / 100;
  //  if (use === 1 || use === 2 || use === 4) {
        console.log("step 1");
        cpub = bud * 30 / 100;
        gpub = bud * 30 / 100;
        mbb = bud * 10 / 100;
        ramb = bud * 10 / 100;
        memoryb = bud * 10 / 100;
        ssdb = bud * 10 / 100;
        if (((document.getElementById("cpu-pref") || {}).value)||"" === 1) { // 1 = intel - 2 = amd
            for (i in pc.cpu)
                {
                    if (pc.cpu[i].price < cpub && pc.cpu[i].make === "intel" && (cpub - pc.cpu[i].price) < cp) {
                            cp = cpub - pc.cpu[i].price;
                            fcpu = pc.cpu[i].name;
                            s = i;
                            console.log("i =" + i);
                            console.log("fcpu =" + fcpu);
                            console.log("cp =" + cp);
                            console.log("cpu =" + cpub);
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                }
            } else {
            for(i in pc.cpu)
                {
                    if (pc.cpu[i].price < cpub && pc.cpu[i].make === "amd" && (cpub - pc.cpu[i].price) < cp) {
                            cp = cpub - pc.cpu[i].price;
                            fcpu = pc.cpu[i].name;
                            s = i;
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                }
            }
            bud = bud - pc.cpu[s].price;
            window.alert(fcpu);
  //  }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve with this code ? it's valid

Comment: this might be a useful tool going forward: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The JSON is valid, except that in pure JSON comments are not allowed. But in JavaScript it is a valid object literal.

Comment: i get so many errors on this, its way bigger and has more like "cpu", and i have a function that is going through all of this data and chose the right one by the input, should i post the function ?

Comment: @YanirCohen That's not JSON, that's an object literal.

Comment: did u see the func im trying to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tools like http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer or http://jsonlint.com/ you can check if your json is valid.
You can't use comment but in javascript everything should be fine.
Without comments your json is valid, anyway.

Comment: yes i know, check out the pc = JSON.parse(ppc) - is it necessary?

Comment: ppc is already an object, you don't need to parse it.  The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you.

Comment: ok i edited it to pc like it was and removed the parse, my code still doesnt work, TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined on that line : bud = bud - pc.cpu[s].price;

Comment: which line ? Check the `s` value here: `bud = bud - pc.cpu[s].price;`

Comment: on that line, s suppose to be to chosen cpu, thanks for helping me dude, its a struggle

Comment: How can you see here http://jsbin.com/terasenewa/edit?js,console,output the `s` value is `undefined` so you code doesn't work, fix that.

Comment: if i only knew how to fix that. how can i get the price with only the name of the cpu?

Comment: if `s`is undefined you should see only `bud` value, it isn't ? So check it! (i.e. `bud = bud - ( (s === undefined) ? 0 : pc.cpu[s].price` ) )

Comment: now i think the problem is in the if statement before the for loops, does it looks valid to u?

Comment: 'Well, you can unify your if condition `pc.cpu[i].price < cpub  && (cpub - pc.cpu[i].price) < cp && (pc.cpu[i].make === "amd" || pc.cpu[i].make === "intel")` and put it into one for loop (The instructions inside the if are the same). You should check why the values that you pass make that condition false.